# Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.a5Y4NP (%build)

Tags: nginx, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build a simple source rpm package for nginx (nginx-1.11.4-1.el6.ngx.src.rpm). But i am not able to build as its giving me errors. I have already followed these two threads.. Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.b1DgAt (%build) and Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ajKra4 (%prep). But nothing seems to be working for me.

I cannot figure out the problem. please help me to fix this.

Comment: you need to show more info about the errors. The import information is earlier in the error messages...

Comment: This is too general request. Show your spec file. Show your error. Without that, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the file ... you can run with "sh -x /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.xxxxxx" if necessary.

You may need to rebuild the binary package to fix the problem.